# Mysql multiple limit

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i have created a query for my packages.

**SQL**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT * FROM wp_posts      
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)     
WHERE 1=1  
    AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '% %')  
       OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '% %')))  
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing_type' 
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
    AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'packageID' 
    AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '4' 
       OR CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '1' 
       OR CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '2' 
       OR CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '3' 
       OR CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = '0' ) ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value  ASC, wp_posts.post_date DESC`
```

It is working fine. But now i want to set limit in each `meta_key` value so based on that i can display the products in my packages.

Thanks

Sanket

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT * 
FROM wp_posts wp 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON (wp.ID = wpm.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND (((wp.post_title LIKE '% %') OR (wp.post_content LIKE '% %'))) AND 
      wp.post_type = 'listing_type' AND wp.post_status IN ('publish', 'private') AND 
      wpm.meta_key = 'packageID' AND wpm.meta_value IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY wp.ID 
ORDER BY wpm.meta_value  ASC, wp.post_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: it is working fine but my issue is to get random product for each meta_value.And for that i need to set the limit in it.suppose in meta_value='0' there is 10 products but i want to display two random record from it. in meta_value='2' i want to display 5 random record from it.like this i want to get from the sql.